# B+ Tree builbing from scratch

Tags: database, database-design, tree, modeling

I've being trying to build this b+ tree and was unable to do it. the tree of order 2 (4 maximum nodes & 2 minimum) should have the following entries 23, 65, 37, 60, 46, 92, 48, 71, 56, 59, 18, 21, 10, 74, 78, 15, 16, 20, 24, 28, 39, 43, 47, 50, 69, 75, 8, 49, 33, 38.

This is what I got:

Root:   46

1st Level: {28,46,60}

2nd Level: L1={15,18,23}, L2={37,39}, L3= {48,56}, L4= {71,78}

3rd Level: L11= {8,10},L12= {15,16},L13= {18,20,21},L14= {23,24}, L21= {28,33},L22= {37,38}, L23= {39,43}, L31= {28,33},L32= {37,38},L33= {39,43}, L41= {60,65,69}, L42= {71,74,75}, L43= {78,92}

Please let me know if I made any mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look right to me.

You can [watch the tree getting generated](http://ysangkok.github.io/js-clrs-btree/btree.html#%7B%22actions%22%3A%5B%5B%22initTree%22%2C%7B%22keys%22%3A%5B%5D%7D%2C2%5D%2C%5B%22insert%22%2C23%5D%2C%5B%22insert%22%2C65%5D%2C%5B%22insert%22%2C37%5D%2C%5B%22insert%22%2C60%5D%2C%5B%22insert%22%2C46%5D%2C%5B%22insert%22%2C92%5D%2C%5B%22insert%22%2C48%5D%2C%5B%22insert%22%2C71%5D%2C%5B%22insert%22%2C56%5D%2C%5B%22insert%22%2C59%5D%2C%5B%22insert%22%2C18%5D%2C%5B%22insert%22%2C21%5D%2C%5B%22insert%22%2C10%5D%2C%5B%22insert%22%2C74%5D%2C%5B%22insert%22%2C78%5D%2C%5B%22insert%22%2C15%5D%2C%5B%22insert%22%2C16%5D%2C%5B%22insert%22%2C20%5D%2C%5B%22insert%22%2C24%5D%2C%5B%22insert%22%2C28%5D%2C%5B%22insert%22%2C39%5D%2C%5B%22insert%22%2C43%5D%2C%5B%22insert%22%2C47%5D%2C%5B%22insert%22%2C50%5D%2C%5B%22insert%22%2C69%5D%2C%5B%22insert%22%2C75%5D%2C%5B%22insert%22%2C8%5D%2C%5B%22insert%22%2C49%5D%2C%5B%22insert%22%2C33%5D%2C%5B%22insert%22%2C38%5D%2C%5B%22stop%22%5D%5D%7D). Here's the result:

[image: B-Tree result]